# HighCharts usar método para preencher séries

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp

Estou a fazer uma aplicação em Asp.Net que esta a usar gráficos HighChart e a função javascript que estou a usar é esta (tirado da net e colocado na pagina aspx):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'User Progress'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Saba Data'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

    }]
});
   });
   </script>
```

Eu tenho um método que me preenche uma gridview na pagina aspx.cs:

```
 using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["SabaDataOra"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            //string str = "select * from (" +  query1 + ")xpto where xpto.domain in (" + subquery + ")";

            string str = query1;

            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(str, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("organization", DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("locale_id", DropDownList3.SelectedValue.ToString()));

                //cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("domains", subquery));
                try
                {
                    using (OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {

                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(ds);



                        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                        {
                            reportORGview.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                            reportORGview.DataBind();

                            if (reportORGview.HeaderRow != null && Label1.Text.ToString().Equals("User_Progress"))
                            {
                                reportORGview.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "Domain";
                                reportORGview.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Text = "Organization";
                                reportORGview.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Text = "Firstname";
                                reportORGview.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Text = "Lastname";
                                reportORGview.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Text = "Username";
                                reportORGview.HeaderRow.Cells[5].Text = "Person Created Date";
                                reportORGview.HeaderRow.Cells[6].Text = "Course ID";
                                reportORGview.HeaderRow.Cells[7].Text = "Course Name";
                                reportORGview.HeaderRow.Cells[8].Text = "Content Name";
                                reportORGview.HeaderRow.Cells[9].Text = "Subscription Date";
                                reportORGview.HeaderRow.Cells[10].Text = "First Launch Date";
                                reportORGview.HeaderRow.Cells[11].Text = "Last Access Module";
                                reportORGview.HeaderRow.Cells[12].Text = "Percentage of Completion";
                                reportORGview.HeaderRow.Cells[13].Text = "Completion Date";
                                reportORGview.HeaderRow.Cells[14].Text = "Time Spent";
```

Como é que eu faço para usar colunas por exemplo a 2 e a 5 desse método em vez de valore fixos que estão no exemplo do gráfico?
Agradeço ajuda ASAP. 
Obrigado